# Converting nvarchar(255) in SQL Server to varchar in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, varchar, nvarchar

I am using CData Sync to convert my table in SQL Server to MariaDB. The data type I have for some of my columns (including my primary key) is nvarchar(255) and when I try to convert it using CData sync to a MariaDB table, it throws an error stating: `#1170 error (42000) blob/Text Column Used in key specification without a key length`. In the table mapping section in CData I see the column data types are being mapped correctly (nvarchar to varchar) but I think because the length on the source table is nvarchar(255) it's converting to varchar(510)? Which is too big so it's reading varchar as a TEXT/BLOB instead? None of my columns are specified as TEXT/BLOB so I'm not sure where CData Sync is getting that from. How do I convert nvarchar(255) to varchar? Would it be varchar(255) or varchar(512)?

Comment: Given the obtuse way [SQL Server defines nvarchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#nchar---n--), I'd suspect the `varchar(510)` is the solution that accounts for all the values possibly stored there. What character set do you have in these columns? What length of the 255 "byte-pairs" are you using? What character set is being used in mariadb as the conversion type? The conversion shows CData Sync is definately creating a blob/text column.

Comment: im not sure how to check the character set of the columns, but the coallition is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" for the SQL Server table and the max length of the characters used in the column thats erroring out in SQL Server is 30...

Comment: there is no table in MariaDB because of the error from replicating the original table